# Prove: $\overline{(\frac{z_1}{z_2})}=\frac{\overline{z_1}}{\overline{z_2}}$

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

> Prove: $$\overline{\left(\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right)}=\frac{\overline{z_1}}{\overline{z_2}}$$

$$\overline{\left(\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right)}=\overline{z_1\cdot z_2^{-1}}=\overline{z_1}\cdot \overline{z_2^{-1}}=\overline{z_1}\cdot \overline{z_2}^{-1}=\frac{\overline{z_1}}{\overline{z_2}}$$

Just to be sure is it valid?

Comment: If $z_1=wz_2$ then $\overline z_1=\overline w\overline z_2$.

Comment: It rather depends what you have already proved - which previous results can be quoted. Ideally you would set out the proof showing which previous result you are using to justify each step.

Comment: I think the step which needs justification here is `3->4` and perhaps `2->3`.

Answer (score 3):

Note: The step $\overline{z_2^{-1}}=\overline{z_2}^{-1}$ need a proof, if you follow my solution you can see why.

**Solution:** You know that $|z|^2=z\cdot \bar{z}$

Given $|z_2|\neq 0$, $\dfrac{z_1}{z_2}=\dfrac{z_1\bar{z_2}}{|z_2|^2}$

Then $\overline{\Big(\dfrac{z_1}{z_2}\Big)}=\dfrac{\bar{z_1}{z_2}}{|z_2|^2}=\dfrac{\bar{z_1}}{\bar{z_2}}$

Comment: @Shuri2060 hello!!! why not !!! I showed why $\overline{z_2^{-1}}=\overline{z_2}^{-1}$ in my solution...

Comment: My bad - your edit makes that clear now

Answer (score 2):

**other approach**

put $$z_1=r_1e^{it_1} $$
and $$z_2=r_2e^{it_2} $$

then
$$z=\frac {z_1}{z_2}=\frac {r_1}{r_2}e^{i (t_1-t_2)} .$$

$$\overline {z}=\frac {r_1}{r_2}e^{-i (t_1-t_2)} $$

$$=\frac {r_1e^{-it_1}}{r_2e^{-it_2}} $$
$$=\frac {\overline {z_1}}{\overline {z_2}} $$

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question asks whether the steps in the solution are valid?

Comment: @Shuri2060 You can give other answers for other users.

Comment: Looking at this now, it proves `3->4` using polar form - yes, that justifies that step, but perhaps make it clear what you're doing.

Comment: @Salahamam_ Fatima Why $e^{i(t_1-t_2)}=\frac{e^{it_1}}{e^{it_2}}$? I think we need to prove this thing. See please my solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think your proof is not  full. Why $\overline{z^{-1}}=\overline{z}^{-1}$? Why $\overline{z_1z_2^{-1}}=\overline{z_1}\overline{z^{-1}}$?

I think it's better to make the following.

Let $z_1=a+bi$ and $z_2=c+di$, where $\{a,b,c,d\}\subset\mathbb R$ and $c^2+d^2\neq0$.

Thus,
$$\overline{\left(\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right)}=\overline{\left(\frac{a+bi}{c+di}\right)}=\overline{\left(\frac{(a+bi)(c-di)}{c^2+d^2}\right)}=$$
$$=\overline{\left(\frac{ac+bd}{c^2+d^2}+\frac{bc-ad}{c^2+d^2}i\right)}=\frac{ac+bd}{c^2+d^2}-\frac{bc-ad}{c^2+d^2}i=$$
$$=\frac{(a-bi)(c+di)}{c^2+d^2}=\frac{a-bi}{c-di}=\frac{\overline{z_1}}{\overline{z_2}}.$$

Comment: @Shuri2060 I fixed my post. Is now it OK?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Se page 25 of https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bx5UtfcIyfwfRnhkci1GazNLS0k/edit, at the end.

Comment: @123 What is not clear in my proof?

Comment: @Shuri2060 Isn't easier with polar form. No?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I am not talking about your proof but your claim at that proof in the question is not complete.

Comment: @Salahamam_ Fatima In the polar form we need to prove properties of the polar form before.

Comment: @123 Why? Where exactly my proof is not complete?

Comment: I think @123's point is your first line 'I think your proof is not so good' might imply that the proof is incorrect rather than lacking a few steps.

Comment: @Shuri2060 I fixed. Now it's OK? Thank you! Just my English is very bad.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this one in two parts.

> If $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers, then $\overline{zw}=\overline{z}\,\overline{w}$.

Suppose $z=a+bi$ and $w=c+di$ with $a,b,c,d$ real numbers. Then
$$
\overline{zw} = \overline{(a+bi)(c+di)} = \overline{ac-bd + i(ad+bc)}
= ac-bd-i(ad+bc)
= (a-bi)(c-di)
= \overline{z}\,\overline{w}.
$$

> If $z$ is a nonzero complex number, then $1/\overline{z}=\overline{(1/z)}$.

Suppose $z=a+bi$ with $a$ and $b$ real numbers such that $(a,b)\ne(0,0)$. Then
$$
\overline{\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}
= \overline{\left(\frac{1}{a+bi}\right)}
= \overline{\left(\frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}\right)}
= \overline{\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}i}
= \frac{a}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}i
= \frac{a+bi}{a^2+b^2}
= \frac{1}{a-bi}
= \frac{1}{\overline{z}}.
$$

---

Now
$$
\overline{\left(\frac{z}{w}\right)}
= \overline{\left(z\frac{1}{w}\right)} = \overline{z}\overline{\left(\frac{1}{w}\right)}
= \overline{z} \frac{1}{\overline{w}}
= \frac{\overline{z}}{\overline{w}}.
$$
This is essentially what you did.